# After running dconf reset -f/ under 16.04 LTS how can I correct my environment for RDC?

Tags: rdp

I used the following command `dconf reset -f /`
 [from](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/how-to-reset-ubuntu-desktop-to-default) to reset my desktop environment. The issue that I currently have is that I can still ssh into the machine, but connecting via Remmina  fails with the following error `Unable to connect to VNC server`.

Is there a way from the command line to reset things back to normal. I tried to rebuild using this [reference](https://linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04/), but the normal functionality was lacking.

Comment: Hmmm. Are you asking a question about getting Remmina to work?  Or are you asking about undoing all the changes you made? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I believe that I have framed the question in to clarify - undoing all the changes that I have made. Do you have any suggestions? I would hate o to reinstall my operating system :)

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [article](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-848128.html) I was able to find a solution by purchasing a [headless ghost, display emulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075ZMVGQS) . I am now able to connect via RDC and SSH.